# from torchvision import _C ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to use facebook's AX platform to find the optimal values of hyper parameters for my machine learning model.For that I have tried installing the ax platform using:

```
pip3 install ax-platform
```

Once I have installed , I have tried to import the following into my spyder notebook

```
from ax.plot.contour import plot_contour
from ax.plot.trace import optimization_trace_single_method
from ax.service.managed_loop import optimize
from ax.utils.notebook.plotting import render, init_notebook_plotting
from ax.utils.tutorials.cnn_utils import load_mnist, train, evaluate, CNN
```

I am getting an error in the last line:`from ax.utils.tutorials.cnn_utils import load_mnist, train, evaluate, CNN`

> from torchvision import _C  ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

My python version is `Python 3.7.4` and my anaconda version is `conda 4.7.10`
I am new to pytorch and ax platform.I don't have much clue why this is happening.Can someone please help me?